# Sufficient conditions for Leibniz integral rule when variable limits cancel out

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

Say we have 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\int_0^{f(x)}g(x,y)dy+\int_{f(x)}^1h(x,y)dy\right]$$
where all functions are continuous, and $g$ and $h$ are continuously differentiable with respect to $x$, and $0<f<1$, and $g(x,f(x))=h(x,f(x))$.

The Leibniz integral rule says that if $f$ is continuously differentiable the solution is
$$\int_0^{f(x)}\frac{dg(x,y)}{dx}dy+\int_{f(x)}^1\frac{dh(x,y)}{dx}dy+\frac{df(x)}{dx}[g(x,f(x))-h(x,f(x))]$$
$$=\int_0^{f(x)}\frac{dg(x,y)}{dx}dy+\int_{f(x)}^1\frac{dh(x,y)}{dx}dy$$

My question is: does $f$ need to be continuously differentiable to get the second line of this result? It would seem to me that the other properties listed are sufficient.

Comment: You don't need the differentiability of $f$, but without it you have to do some more work to prove the formula. Let $$k(x,y) = \begin{cases} g(x,y) &, y \leqslant f(x) \\ h(x,y) &, y \geqslant f(x) \end{cases}$$ and consider the difference quotient $$\int_0^1 \frac{k(x+t,y) - k(x,y)}{t}\,dy.$$

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I don't immediately see how to get past the fact that $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}$ of the difference quotient you wrote is undefined at the point $y=f(x)$.

Comment: The thing is that this doesn't matter, because it's a single point. $\frac{1}{t}(k(x+t,y) - k(x,y))$ is bounded, and it converges everywhere except at $y = f(x)$ - even locally uniformly, which is quite helpful when you're dealing with Riemann integrals.

Comment: OK thanks. So essentially $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^1kdy$ can be represented as a sum of derivatives of three integrals: (i) a neighbourhood around $y=f(x)$, (ii) $y$ above this neighbourhood and (iii) $y$ below it. As the size of the neighbourhood goes to zero (ii) and (iii) become the integrals of the derivatives of $g$ and $h$, and (i) can be ignored because its limits converge and the integrand is bounded. Is this on track?

Comment: Basically that's it. Do you want to fill out the details and post an answer?

Comment: Thanks. I would like to but unfortunately I cannot spare the time it would take me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45011/discussion-between-jimmy-and-daniel-fischer).